Error with System.Data.SqlClient in a C# compiled DLL
I have this problem:
I take a C# DLL project from a PC of a collaborator that has been fired.
I have resolved all orphan dependencies.
I compile the DLL, load it into the CAD program but, when i ran the connection command to the database I got this error:
ERROR WINDOWS
The (uncopyable) Windows error dialog reads:
"Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click...[]...   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version 0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey....."
The original project natively uses System.Data.SqlClient but this IS NOT listed in the dependencies list.
Also the error indicates a 0.0.0.0 for the version, so I don't know what is the correct version to add via NuGet.
I pass the code from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022 but the .NET Framework is 4.7.2 in both environnement.
I have tried to add blind packages from nuget but it didn't resolve the issue...
Also, in the config file, the versione of the package is not listed...
How can I resolve?
Regards...

When you asked your question, you were told "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

This question is similar to: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
